# How To Complete Debugging Facebook Mismatch Data?

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, tags, meta

I'm attempting to debug some problems with my Facebook like count using Facebook's open graph. When I fetched information it returned Parser Mismatched Metadata: The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'fb:admins'

What exactly does this mean? I've not done anything with my Facebook page i.e. attempting to alter any code. 
I've attempted to type the meta tags in so that you can read it using ctrl K, they're displaying in this post as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Living Fit, Healthy and Happy (SM)" />`

<meta property="og:site_name" content="Living Fit, Healthy and Happy (SM)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.livingfithealthyandhappy.com/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The health and wellness website committed to helping you lead a healthy life!" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://up3.typepad.com/6a0120a6bbdd83970b01675f189465970b-220si" />
```

That's what it returns, basically this appears to be code for my website, which itself has been on the same host since 2009. Could the above parsing problems be affecting my Facebook like count i.e. that likes are showing up as invites and likes simultaneously?

Comment: can you share the graph api request you use?

Comment: Thanks for offering to help me with this. I'm not very familiar with debugging. What I can say is that I logged into Facebook URL linter to degug and it returned the information I pasted in above. Perhaps you want this information...

Comment: {
   "id": "389135404589",
   "created_time": "2010-04-30T02:28:07+0000",
   "description": "The health and wellness website committed to helping you lead a healthy life!",
   "image": [
      {
         "height": 220,
         "url": "http://up3.typepad.com/6a0120a6bbdd83970b01675f189465970b-220si",
         "width": 220
      }
   ],
   "is_scraped": true,
   "site_name": "Living Fit, Healthy and Happy (SM)",
   "title": "Living Fit, Healthy and Happy (SM)",
   "type": "article",
   "updated_time": "2015-05-24T13:30:58+0000",
   "url": "http://www.livingfithealthyandhappy.com/"
}

Comment: That's the Graph API but how would that affect the like box/like count bugging issue?